# JSON.parse error: invalid character at position 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

For some reason I'm getting a parse error when trying to send a post request to the server

```
$.post("../php/user_handler.php", formData, function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        if(result.status === 'error') {
                $('#' + result.control + '-error').html(result.message).css('display', 'inline-block');
            } else {
                $('#form-message').html(result.message).css('display', 'inline-block');
            }
        });
```

The message I'm getting implies that the error is with the syntax of the first character of the first line, but I really don't understand how; I've checked it against several examples of how to make this request and it looks just fine to me.

Comment: your data is invalid as it seems. What is the content of `data`?

Comment: your **server** is likely sending HTML instead - check the developer tools console to see what the request response data is

Comment: You should log the JSON and check it with [jsonparseronline](http://jsonparseronline.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply means that your string is not JSON. First character has to be "{" or "[" but it is not. Might be empty or start with something else. Dump the thing aout on the console.log before you try to parse it.Might help ;)

Comment: Might be also that your php script is buggy and pump a php error message out to your request or even nothing..